# Regex Exact Match Matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a sentence:

```
I am amazed, but .
```

I would like to replace the space after the `but` character. Currently, I am doing it purely by using matlab's `regexprep` function where the pattern I pass in is `.` (a space and a period.), but it doesn't work.

I am using:

```
regexprep(sentences{i},'\ .\','.')
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `.` is a metacharacter in regular expressions (matching any single character). To match a literal `.`, it must be escaped using `\`:

```
regexprep(sentences{i},' \.','.')
```

The `.` doesn't need escaping in the third argument to regexprep.

(Edited to incorporate the change in the comments below)

Comment: doesn't seem to work, there is still a space between but and the `.`

Comment: Try `regexprep(sentences{i},' \.','.')` The extra \ shouldn't matter, as ` ` is not special, but maybe it does?